# ProGuard optimization also remove #wait() calls

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, proguard

When Proguard optimize my application, it seams that all calls to `Object#wait()` are being removed.

So that each Thread which should passively wait (until notification) is now actively waiting (100% CPU usage).

When the optimizing is shutdown with `-dontoptimize` everything is OK.

Has I need the optimization for removing some method with `-assumenosideeffects`, I am searching for what's wrong.
Is it possible to preserve all calls to `Object#wait()` to be optimized (removed)?

Is there any other solution?

EDIT 1:
For example this code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    isRunning = true;
    try {
        while (isRunning) {
            if (parent.isActivate) {
                parent.updateDriveButtons();
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(1000);
                }
            }
            else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    // Wait for that the page is activated.
                    Utils.wait(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

is being replaced by this code (after decompiling the optimized code):
`wait()` has been removed and only the synchronize is visible with `monitorenter;` ... `monitorexit;`

```
 public final void run()
  {
    this.isRunning = true;
    try {
      while (this.isRunning) {
        if (this.parent.isShowing()) {
          ...
          monitorenter;
          monitorexit; continue;
        }

        monitorenter;

        monitorexit;
      }return;
    } catch (Throwable localThrowable) {
      Object Ljava/lang/Object;;
      return;
    } finally {
      this.isRunning = false; } throw localObject1;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem? Have you really verified that calls to `wait()` are really being removed? Is it possible that you actually just have some flawed code, and the optimization is just making that flaw more visible?

Comment: I have added an example which demonstrate this issue

Comment: monitorenter would already be present due to the synchronized block... so the `wait` call isn't being *replaced* by that. If it's being *removed* then yes, that sounds like a bug. Again, a short but *complete* example (ideally a complete class that can be compiled, then the command line you're using for Proguard) would make life easier for those trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this gives me energy to try to isolate the problem. Making a little application which tries to reproduce this issue was not possible, but it has helps to find the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be specifying `-assumenosideeffects` options that also match `Object#wait()`. ProGuard then happily removes those calls for you. You probably shouldn't add `-assumenosideeffects` options beyond the ones that are documented in the ProGuard manual.

Comment: Yes, you're right, never the less I mean it's an happily dangerous issue. I try to remove each of my '-assumenosideeffects' until I found the killer.It was '-assumenosideeffects class com.st.utils.ShapeCheck {*;}'. This means that Proguard do not only remove the method defined in ShapeCheck but also all method defined in 'java.lang.Object'!