# Proguard ate my Object.wait()

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I just found that ProGuard removed a .wait() call which I used to synchronize threads, which lead to a race condition which lead to a day of happy debugging :) Anyway...

I tracked it down to following piece of proguard configuration:

```
-assumenosideeffects public class android.util.Log {
    <methods>;
}
```

I want to understand **WHY** this happened. I am not sure why assuming that removal of Log class has no side effects leads to removal of .wait() on different class/object.

I saw [ProGuard optimization also remove #wait() calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495588/proguard-optimization-also-remove-wait-calls) where Eric explains that such things may happen. However, he doesn't explain why.

Also, I found example how to remove Logs here (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html). So, I can replace this piece of proguard of configuration (but it's not the point of this question).

Comment: May I ask you a question... Why are you using ProGuard? For what?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: Code obfuscation mainly. However, log removal is nice addition to overall application obfuscation. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because I think it's not worth your time. Check code generated by ProGuard (decompile apk). You will see that you can easily read the "obfuscated" version. You can remove logs with simple `boolean DEBUG = false` flag. I throwed away ProGuard, since it was giving more problems than benefits.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: I don't know. I would say it's first time when I had real problems with Proguard. Proguard is quite good with renaming all the classes, methods (so the code become nameless). Also, as I remember "boolean DEBUG=false", doesn't remove logs from the binary (they are just not written). So, I am not sure that I am ready to get rid of it.

Comment: If you make `if (DEBUG) Log.d("")` and `DEBUG` will be `false`, `javac` will remove that, because it's unreachable code.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: Probably you right. I didn't look at this (javac code optimization) for quite long time. However, removing the logs is just small piece of overall obfuscation strategy.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk, correct, but AFAIK that only happens if `DEBUG` is declared `static final`.

Comment: @VictorRonin *Obfuscation strategy* are too big words for what ProGuard is doing in my opinion. I can say that guys from [IOCCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest) are really obfuscating code in a way that it makes it hard to read, they have *obfuscation strategy*. But ProGuard? Please just use for example [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to see by yourself that it's easy to read code or find some private key. And for sure somebody who wants to read your code and know what a decompilation is will have no bigger problems.

Comment: @323go `final` is enough, you can test it with `javap -c Classfile`.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: I am happy to discuss this, but comments are quite short. Do you mind sending me an email (I have it in my SO profile).

Comment: ProGuard removes all information that is not necessary for executing the application (debug information and unused code). It reduces code size, improves performance, and it's generally a good first step for protecting applications. If you need more: DexGuard actively fights reverse-engineering, with techniques that are not suitable for an open-source program. (I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk ProGuard also does a lot of bytecode optimisation; not just obfuscation. I prefer using ProGuard to remove logs since it's easy to remove specific levels, which is far nicer than writing logging boilerplate or manually wrapping every single logging call in an if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original configuration matches all methods of Log (explicit or inherited), including Object#wait(). It tells ProGuard that the wait() method has no side-effects and that it can be removed without harming the program. This is obviously not true, as you have noticed. With -assumenosideeffects, you should always explicitly list the methods that are safe to remove.

Comment: Does this mean that configuration "<methods>;" guaranteed to break synchronization if it's defined on any class?

Comment: Yes, it will remove all invocations of wait(), notify(), and notifyAll() in application code, which is very likely to break synchronization.

Comment: Did you consider returning an error if <methods> is defined in a class (exactly my case)? It looks like if it's not an interface - it just asks for troubles.